# How to change html to liquid Shopify?

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I'm doing a site in Shopify and I'm using supply theme, I want to use my own menu instead of using Shopify menu. I wrote code in HTML and CSS but I was wondering if it is possible for someone to help me to change following code in liquid because my friend does not know any HTML and CSS and for him, it's easier to change it through the liquid.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .header {
    background: red;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 250px;
}

.column a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="header">
        <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
      </div>   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 1</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 2</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 3</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div style="padding:16px">
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "Write the code for me" platform. You will need to try to write the code on your own and we can help you if you have issues with it. If you can't then there are freelancers and coding agencies than you can pay to write it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Even though I agree with drip's comment:

> StackOverflow is not a "Write the code for me" platform.

Here is some helpful information, Liquid is templating language and there are many places to get you started with Liquid:

- [Shopify - Liquid reference](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid)
- [Shopify - Getting started Guide](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started)
- [Shopify Partners Blog - Learning Liquid](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/topics/learning-liquid)